# Uninstalling the old version and installing the new version of the program

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I am from Poland and I am taking my first steps in writing scripts (vbs, powershell, bat etc.).
We have a software in our company which is called procertum CardManager
We have several versions of this software
I need help in writing an installation script that will check what version is installed on the computer. If the current version is installed, the script should terminate, but if the previous version is installed, the script should uninstall the old version and install the current version. The script will be distributed via Microsoft SCCM. The problem is that the manufacturer uses the same "Uninstallstring" value for each version, so the verification must follow the "DisplayVersion" value.

Looking for information on the internet, I found many commands and ready-made scripts and managed to create a script in powershell. It looks like this:

```
$AllRegAppEntries = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall,HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty -Path $_.pspath}

$FilteredApps = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

foreach ($App in $AllRegAppEntries) {
    if ($App.DisplayName -ilike "*proCertum CardManager*") {

        try {
            $DisplayVersionAsVersion = New-Object System.Version $App.DisplayVersion
        } catch {
            $DisplayVersionAsVersion = New-Object System.Version
        }

        $VersionToCheck = New-Object System.Version "3.5.1.198"

        if ($DisplayVersionAsVersion -lt $VersionToCheck) {
            [void]$FilteredApps.Add($App)
        }
    }
}

foreach ($App in $FilteredApps) {
    
    if ($App.UninstallString -ilike "msiexec*") {
        $GUID = $App.UninstallString.Substring($App.UninstallString.IndexOf("{"))
        $GUID = $GUID.Substring(0, $GUID.IndexOf("}") + 1)
        Write-Host "Running the following command: msiexec.exe /x $GUID /qn /norestart"
        Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/x $GUID /qn /norestart" -Wait
        
    }
}
```

The script in this form works fine, it removes the old version, it needs help to add a command that will start the msiexec installation process of the msi file from a location with the value "%~dp0product.msi" as the installation file will be on the network share that SCCM uses.

Sorry for my English and please help.
Kind regards,
KamilG

when adding the command:
Start-Process "msiexec.exe" "/i ""%~dp0proCertumCardManager-3.5.1.198-64-bit-pl" /qn /quiet"

the script ends with an error:

```
At C:\install\card\install.ps1:29 char:94
+ ... exe" "/i ""%~dp0proCertumCardManager-3.5.1.198-64-bit-pl" /qn /quiet"
+                                                                         ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
At C:\install\card\install.ps1:24 char:49
+     if ($App.UninstallString -ilike "msiexec*") {
+                                                 ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
At C:\install\card\install.ps1:22 char:33
+ foreach ($App in $FilteredApps) {
+                                 ~
Missing closing '}' in statement block or type definition.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Comment: Issue is do to double quotes in the arguments.  Try creating a new variable with single quotes around the arguments (including Wait) :  $arguments = '"/x $GUID /qn /norestart" -Wait' The change command to without the double quotes around the executable : Start-Process msiexec.exe $arguments

Comment: `%~dp0` is .bat not .ps1.  If this is an msi file, you can install it with `install-package` and uninstall with `uninstall-package`.

Comment: @js2010
The installation file is msi. How to use the uninstall-package and install-package commands if the msi file is on a network share

Comment: `install-package file.msi` and `get-package '*proCertum CardManager*' | uninstall-package`

Comment: @jdweng

I'm sorry but I'm a beginner in powershell, how correctly should this command look like?: Start-Process msiexec.exe $arguments

Comment: Yes that will work

Comment: or `cmd /c msiexec /i dir1\file1.msi /qb` and it waits

Comment: Unfortunately, there are errors all the time. Maybe powershel is not the best choice in this case after all. Maybe try the bat script. Generally, what I need is:

-Check version of *proCertum CardManager* by Display Version

-if version 3.5.1.198 AND it is new version then

GOTO :END

else

GOTO :INSTALL

:INSTALL
REM Uninstall Older version  
start /wait msiexec.exe /x {*****GUID**of DisplayVersion} /qn

REM Install latest version
start /wait msiexec.exe /i "%~dp0proCertumCardManager-3.5.1.198-64-bit-pl.msi" /qn /quiet


:END

Comment: From what you've shown us, you appear to have a quote-imbalance. `"[1 open]/i "[2 or 0 open]"[3 or 1]%~dp0proCertumCardManager-3.5.1.198-64-bit-pl"[2 or 0] /qn /quiet"[1 or -1]`

Comment: Request to administrators to close this topic

Comment: I think the issue is much simpler than this, use `fc` with `if errorlevel` and you will see the way clearly

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/fc

and 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/if